# Aumann's paper: an acronym

Tags: game-theory

Is anybody aware what means [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/876c/48aeda734d06de04ff07e21bf7902a8af2f8.pdf?_ga=2.225975635.817001950.1574000084-1180263575.1574000084) on the page 307, -3rd paragraph the acronym "framework of F. of S." ? I.e. what the letters F. and S. stand for ?

Comment: I googled ""Consequences might appropriately be called states of the person, as opposed to states of the world," to get to the source, Foundations of Statistics by Savage.

Comment: OK. How did you infer that it is the name of a book Foundations of Statistics ? There is no literature at the end of this chapter.

Comment: As I say, I googled the quoted passage  and got [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=N_bBAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=%22Consequences+might+appropriately+be+called+states+of+the+person,+as+opposed+to+states+of+the+world,%22&source=bl&ots=8trFXAfn0i&sig=ACfU3U0Th31IIYylMYPfTgjEyUlwsV5rsg&hl=en&ppis=_c&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj96biKu_HlAhXJnuAKHdJhCVAQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Consequences%20might%20appropriately%20be%20called%20states%20of%20the%20person%2C%20as%20opposed%20to%20states%20of%20the%20world%2C%22&f=false) hit.

Comment: @lulu You are smart. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is referring to the book, The Foundations of Statistics, by the sender Leonard J. Savage

Comment: Great. Where did you deduce it from ?

Comment: I googled what it was quoting in the letter. A tip would be to quote "..." the words you want to find, as it will only return results with words matching the quotes exactly.